# Reputation changes after +100 site bonus displayed wrong. Upvotes temporarily displayed with 120 too much rep

Tags: bug, reputation

I recently achieved more than 200 rep. This triggered the +100 site bonus for stackoverflow, meta, and superuser. When I checked my stackoverflow reputation activity I saw my latest upvote rep gain to be +170. After refresh it corrected to +50.

Comment: This is a longstanding bug (introduced with the profile redesign) that affects _any_ reputation gain, not just the association bonus.

Comment: I have a [write-up explaining the bug on RPG meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12332).

Comment: @VLAZ +1 if you care for RPG meta rep ...

Comment: @rene thanks, my plan is to find so many jobs with the RPG meta rep that I'll be able to buy Jeff Bezos. Every little bit helps.